# Looking for a decreasing function which initially decreases slowly and then decreases fast after a point

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I am looking for a nice decreasing function $f(t)$ for modelling, which starts at a maximum value of $1$ initially i.e. $f(0) = 1$, then decreases slowly initially until a value of $m$ ($0 < m < 1$) in time $t_{1}$ i.e $f(t_{1} = m)$. After $t_{1}$, the function quickly decreases and its value at time $t_{2}$ is near $0$ ($f(t_{2}) \approx 0$).

I have few points so fitting spline or other polynomials overshoot the maximum value of 1. I can threshold the value to 1, but the straight line looks ugly. The second constraint of $f(t_{2} \approx 0$) is not strict, provided the value falls rapidly after $t_{1}$.

Should I try to generate more points and try curve fitting or is there any other solution?

[image]

Comment: Ellipse in the first quadrant?

Comment: $(1-t_2)^{1/n}$ will also behave like that. By increasing $n$ you'll make the slow decreasing part longer and the behavior at the end steeper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

A simple family of curve is
$$
y=1-\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^n
$$

where you can use the parameter $a$ to fit the point $t_2$ in your graph and the value of $n\ge2$ determine how ''flat'' is the curve at the top and can be used to fit the point $(t_1,m)$.

Comment: is it possible to get a curve like this when fitting with glm?